# Controllable IC/MUX that can switch between Logic, Variable Power, or Ground

Tags: power, digital-logic, multiplexer

I am working on a PCB project that is meant to be attached to various different devices. Each device attached to it will have different pin-outs. Each pin has to be customized through an interface where I can set the function for each pin individually. The pins can each be one of four things:

1. Power (Variable 3.3-24 V)
2. Ground
3. An LED (Could be a single LED or a string of LEDs; likely an LED driver)
4. An addressable LED Data Line or a tactile switch (controlled/read by a microcontroller pin)

In order to accomplish this, the best thing I have found is an analog multiplexer ([TMUX1204DGSR](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/TMUX1204)) to switch each pin to the desired function. I am unsure about whether a multiplexer would be able to handle the power/ground side of things.

Am I looking at the right type of IC for this application? If not, what should I be looking at?

[image]

Comment: Please provide data sheet links to the devices mentioned.

Comment: What power level is needed?  You could accomplish this with an SSR (opto coupler solid state relay) if the power level isn't too high.

Comment: The answer depends a lot on the devices that you will want to attach.  Tell us what they are (preferably post links to datasheets).  Tell us what you ultimately want to accomplish with your entire system.  [I'd be surprised if there is a 4-way multiplexer IC which can conduct appreciable amount of power continuously.]

Comment: @MaximusBurkus  Do these attachment devices already exist (I mean designed and made by some 3rd party) ?  Or, are you designing the attachments yourself?  If you are designing them yourself, then you should have more options.

Comment: @NickAlexeev Nick, they are already made, I am trying to build this as a test fixture for our company, because we make custom membrane switch keypads for our customers and many times we need to light them up or test them for demonstration purposes. I have added a diagram to the original post which should help understanding.